# How to search and highlight text in objectlistview in winform

Tags: winforms, highlight, objectlistview, searchable, textrenderer

I want to write an application to search and highlight multiple text in `ObjectListView`.

[image]

`ObjectListView` is able to set defaultRenderer but I can't use multiple `HighLightTextRenderer`.
I need to 6 renderer with 6 color and text different as image work together.
Is there any way to apply to search and highlight multiple text in `ObjectListView` ?

Comment: You want to highlight "123" in red while also highlighting "456" in green for example? Does this make sense from a usability standpoint?

Comment: Yes, I want to set highlight for different text like your example. Do you have any way? I'm using ObjectListView in Winform

Comment: I hope to highlight searched text, But It's a good idea to make many search box with different color